# How do I do redo (i.e. "undo undo") in Vim?

Tags: vim, undo, redo

In Vim, I did too much undo. How do I undo this (that is, redo)?

Comment: as I already collected 2 close votes, I think this belongs here as vim is a programmer's editor.

Comment: I agree, this is programming-related *and* it's a real question.

Comment: Someone around here goes around and marks every Vim question as "belongs on SU" despite the community having long ago decided that Vim belongs on SO, it being a programming tool.

Comment: @Brian: Do you have a link to the document where this consensus was reached?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22963/where-should-developer-computer-setup-questions-go

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20251/where-to-ask-a-question-about-an-ide but I recall this coming up last year sometime.  Vim/Emacs are IDEs.  Moreover the languages used in the config files for both are Turing-complete scripting languages, so the act of setting up Vim is itself programming to begin with.

Comment: @Elyasin: Existing questions are not migrated to new networks.

Answer (score 942, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>

Comment: I would just like to throw the undoTree plugin out there, super awesome for the times you have seemingly screwed yourself with a flurry of undos and redos.

Comment: If I am reading about vi, then my fingers just act on their own.  The vi commands do not work on stackoverflow. :-)

Comment: Note to Mac users: Ctrl + r in a Mac terminal will ruin your day in vim. Don't know the proper key combo in Mac terminal to undo, but it's most definitely NOT Ctrl + r !

Comment: @tpartee I just used Ctrl+r in vim under macOS's Terminal app - no problems here.

Comment: Maybe @tpartee meant `Cmd + r` messes things up? It certainly does something weird; but `Ctrl + r` just worked fine for me (Mac + tmux + vim)

Comment: For some reason, in my case `Ctrl + r` sends Vim into the background process instead of un-doing. So I need to do `fg` in order to bring it back. Not sure what is the reason. Using `iTerm2` to connect an Ubuntu machine with `zsh` (and oh-my-zsh) installed.

Answer (score 139):

Also check out `:undolist`, which offers multiple paths through the undo history. This is useful if you accidentally type something after undoing too much.

Comment: @amindfv: take the number from `:undolist` and type `:undo 178` (say) to rewind to step 178.

Comment: is there any way to show what exactly will be undo'ed in `:undolist`?

Comment: @csharpfolk Use the undotree plugin (https://github.com/mbbill/undotree)

Answer (score 55):

Use `:earlier`/`:later`. To redo everything you just need to do

```
later 9999999d
```

(assuming that you first edited the file at most 9999999 days ago), or, if you remember the difference between current undo state and needed one, use `Nh`, `Nm` or `Ns` for hours, minutes and seconds respectively. + `:later N<CR>` <=> `Ng+` and `:later Nf` for file writes.

Comment: `:later` worked for me in `vi` (not vim -- searched for "vi" on google but all results are for "vim"), thanks!

Comment: @Luc Almost everywhere where you have `vi` command it is a symlink to a vim executable or a copy of it. Not completely everywhere though.

Comment: @ZyX I wish that was true. I only use vi after bash throws a `vim: command not found`. Next thing I do is `alias vim=vi` because I type it so automatically, but it's the plain old vi nevertheless. Also, redo (ctrl+r) would have worked properly had vi been an alias for vim.

Comment: 9999999d is 27395 years ago. I assume the undo feature was not implemented in vi back then. You might want to save yourself some exhaustive typing effort and use a reasonable number. 9999d correspongs to about 27 years, 999d to 2.7 years. I guess in most cases that's enough ...

Answer (score 48):

[Vim documentation](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/undo.html)

```
<Undo>      or                  *undo* *<Undo>* *u*
u           Undo [count] changes.  {Vi: only one level}

                            *:u* *:un* *:undo*
:u[ndo]         Undo one change.  {Vi: only one level}

                            *CTRL-R*
CTRL-R          Redo [count] changes which were undone.  {Vi: redraw screen}

                            *:red* *:redo* *redo*
:red[o]         Redo one change which was undone.  {Vi: no redo}

                            *U*
U           Undo all latest changes on one line.  {Vi: while not
            moved off of it}
```

Answer (score 32):

In command mode, use the <kbd>U</kbd> key to undo and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> to redo. Have a look at http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/undo.html.

Comment: How about in insert mode?

Comment: @YuFengShen the power of vim is in the command mode. we don't need redo in insert mode

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken.

Answer (score 15):

First press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to exit from edit mode.

Then,

For *undo*, use <kbd>u</kbd> key as many times you want to undo.

For *redo*, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>r</kbd> key

Answer (score 11):

Refer to the ["undo" and "redo" part of Vim document](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/undo.html#redo).

**:red[o]** (Redo one change which was undone) and {count} <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> (Redo {count} changes which were undone) are both ok.

Also, the **:earlier** {count} (go to older text state {count} times) could always be a substitute for undo and redo.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>

*The "r" is lower-case.*

Comment: Actually, it shouldn't matter -- traditional consoles have no distinction between `^r` and `^R`, and Vim follows that.

Comment: @ephemient: agreed. In MS-DOS, you can't even type a lowercase `^X` (where `X` can be any letter).

Comment: In Vim, Ctrl-shift-R (ctrl with uppercase R) is replace mode.

Answer (score 4):

**Using VsVim for Visual Studio?**

I came across this when experimenting with VsVim, which provides [bindings for Vim commands in Visual Studio](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim).

I know about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> in Vim itself, but this particular binding does not work in VsVim (at least not in my setup?).

What *does* work however, is the command `:red`. This is a little bit more of a hassle than the above, but it is still fine when you really need it.

Comment: Downvoted because the question is asking specifically about vim, not Visual Studio.

Comment: @JohnVonNeumann This *is* related to Vim, or at least vim bindings, just in the context of VS. That`s what brought me to this question, after all. Punishing someone for adding a little more info seems a little harsh and uncalled for don't you think, even if it does perhaps expand slightly beyond the scope of the OP?

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer seems to work?
Quite annoying, as undo/redo's are something VsVim seems to be especially bad at

Answer (score 3):

Practically speaking, the `:undolist` is hard to use and Vim’s `:earlier` and `:later` time tracking of changes is only usable for course-grain fixes.

Given that, I resort to a plug-in that combines these features to provide a visual tree of browsable undos, called “Gundo.”

Obviously, this is something to use only when you need a fine-grained fix, or you are uncertain of the exact state of the document you wish to return to. See: *[Gundo. Graph your Vim undo tree in style](https://sjl.bitbucket.io/gundo.vim/)*